# Как отобразить в VS Code только нужные темы?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Можно ли настроить отображение тем в выпадающем меню VS Code (Ctrl K, Ctrl T), а именно оставить только те темы, которыми пользуюсь?
Например совсем не пользуюсь светлыми и высококонтрастными темами, а также некоторыми вариантами из установленного "пакета" тем (например только GitHub Dark из всего списка GitHub Theme). Хотелось бы, что бы все варианты тем, которыми не пользуюсь, не отображались в меню.
Как это настроить?

Answer (score 0):

Можно в поиске по расширениям набрать `@builtin`, чтобы открыть список встроенных расширений, которые иначе не видны.

Там можно выключить лишние встроенные темы.

> только GitHub Dark из всего списка GitHub Theme

Тут этот прием не поможет.